# View with a concatenated text field with line breaks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, view

Using SQL Server 2012, I need to create a view with a field that concatenates a log field from another table, roughly:

```
select
    id,
    description,
    STUFF((
        SELECT
            '------------' + char(13) + char(10) +
            MessageLog.MessageText + char(13) + char(10) +
            '- on ' +
                format(MessageLog.MessageDateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') +
                ' by ' + MessageLog.MessageAuthor + char(13) + char(10)
        FROM
           MessageLog
        WHERE
            Incident.IncidentNumber = MessageLog.IncidentNumber
      ORDER BY MessageLog.MessageDateTime DESC
      FOR XML PATH('')),
    1,
    2,
    ''
    ) AS allMessages
from
    Incident
```

The line breaks (char(13)+char(10)) come back as hex encoded &#x0D; instead of, well, line breaks.  The data from the table gets dumped into an HTML input field and I have no chance for any post-processing.

I have tried storing the line break as just char(13); just char(10); \n; <br />; and just hitting enter between single quotes.  Nothing renders correctly. I am guessing that I am abusing STUFF() / XML but cannot figure out where my mistake is.

How can I create my allMessages value with line breaks?

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16547390/3187747

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I had seen that question and tried it; I believe my output was screwy because of the web front end and I did not realize where the problem laid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this example here
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=138165

```
CREATE TABLE #MessageLog
    (
      MessageText VARCHAR(MAX),
      MessageDateTime VARCHAR(MAX),
      MessageAuthor VARCHAR(MAX),
      IncidentNumber INT
    )

CREATE TABLE #Incident
(
id INT,
[description] VARCHAR(30),
IncidentNumber INT
)

INSERT INTO #MessageLog (MessageText, MessageDateTime, MessageAuthor, IncidentNumber  )
SELECT 'masg1 'MessageText, GETDATE()-6 MessageDateTime,'abc' MessageAuthor, 4 IncidentNumber
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'msg 2'MessageText, GETDATE()-6 MessageDateTime,'abc' MessageAuthor, 4 IncidentNumber
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'msg3'MessageText, GETDATE()-6 MessageDateTime,'abc' MessageAuthor, 3 IncidentNumber

INSERT INTO #Incident
SELECT 1, 'desc', 4
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 'desc', 4
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 'desc', 3

-- the solution
SELECT        STUFF(( SELECT  '------------' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
                        + MessageLog.MessageText + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
                        + '- on ' + MessageLog.MessageDateTime + ' by '
                        + MessageLog.MessageAuthor + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
                FROM    #MessageLog MessageLog
                WHERE   Incident.IncidentNumber = MessageLog.IncidentNumber
                ORDER BY MessageLog.MessageDateTime DESC
              FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE ).value('.[1]','varchar(max)')
              , 1, 2, '') AS allMessages
FROM    #Incident Incident
```

Comment: Thanks to @AA.SC for taking the time to take the link I posted and edit my answer to include a great prototype example!

Comment: But that's just a prototype. What *is* the solution?

Comment: The solution was to have the FOR XML to include the extra stuff after the 
FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE ).value('.[1]','varchar(max)')

Apparently, that extra information tells XML PATH to honor the line feeds.

Comment: I'm so sorry, the solution was there, I only needed to scroll down to see it. I think the big gaps between the statements confused me (especially the one before the solution itself). I've taken the liberty of reducing them to just one empty line each.

Comment: Can you explain the use of "TYPE" and .value?  I am guessing some kind of type casting is going on but could not find references for their use.

Comment: @BillWallace - To be totally honest, I don't fully understand what it does (I haven't fully researched that part) - I just found the example and tested it.  It seemed to do what you wanted, so I wanted to at least get you going on your problem.  If I find more information, I will update the post.

Comment: @BillWallace - I'm not sure if this explains it any better, but have a look here. 
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2010/04/15/handling-special-characters-with-for-xml-path.aspx